# method not functioning correctly

Tags: c#, methods

This method is part of a larger program that pulls employee data from a .txt file and then uses that data to calculate net pay.
My CalcPay method is supposed to figure pay for hours > 40 as well as hours < 40, but when it gets to the employees with more than 40 hours, it figures their pay at just hours * wage as opposed to taking hours > 40 and making them time-and-a-half...any suggestions?

```
public double CalcPay()
    {

        double pay = hoursWorked * hourlyWage;
        double overTimeHours = hoursWorked - FULL_TIME;

        if (overTimeHours > 0)
        {
            pay += overTimeHours * (hourlyWage * OVER_TIME_RATE);
        }
        double tax1 = pay * FED_TAX;
        double tax2 = pay * STATE_TAX;
        return ((pay - tax1) - tax2);
    }
```

Comment: I wonder if person like you should be working on code that calculates employee pay.

Comment: well, that is not polite  :)    i'm a student working on an assignment.

Comment: @Euphoric I'm thinking this is homework

Comment: It looks like your original solution was double counting overtime as overtime AND regular pay.. not good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably do something like this.

```
 public double CalcPay()
    {
        double regularHours = Math.Min(hoursWorked, FULL_TIME);
        double overTimehours = Math.Max(hoursWorked - FULL_TIME, 0);

        double regularPay = regularHours * hourlyWage;
        double overTimePay = overTimehours * hourlyWage * OVER_TIME_RATE;
        double pay = regularPay + overTimePay;

        double tax1 = pay * FED_TAX;
        double tax2 = pay * STATE_TAX;
        return ((pay - tax1) - tax2);
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. when i cut your revised method into my program, it returns the same results i was getting before. So i am still a little lost.

Comment: Maybe your math is wrong and the program's math is right? I tried the example with 50 hours, $10/hr, and 1.5 overtime, and I got $550. That should be $400 (40x10) + (10 * $10 * 1.5) seems right?

Comment: On second thought, check your inputs / constants. Maybe one of those isn't what you thought it is?

Comment: Last thought, I didn't touch your tax calculations. Are they both based off the initial pay? or is one deducted before the other? I had set my tax to zero when I tested it since your question wasn't about the tax.

Comment: the tax deductions should come off after all pay is figured.  total pay - tax1 - tax2 = net pay

Comment: @BXL Can you tell me what inputs you are using, and what you are getting?

Comment: i am using wage as 10.50 and hours as 42 and getting $319.73 and my own hand calculations show i should get 327.34    ......tax1  = .2; tax2 = .075.

Comment: so 40 * 10.50 + ((10.50 * 1.5) * 2) = 451.50; 451.50 - 90.30 - 33.86 should give 327.34, but my program returns 319.73

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20809/discussion-between-bxl-and-alan)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem, as many pointed out the method works as it should, i was reading the inputs out of order which caused the output to be wrong in cases of overtime. thanks to all who offered help.